# String pattern matching in c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, random, number-formatting

I have a function with takes something like a SSN number as argument. The input can be in one of the following formats (validity of SSN is not a factor)

```
999-99-9999
99-999-9999
9-9999-9999
999999999
99999999-9
```

Hyphen can be at any location and input can be of any length.
This method will create a random number with same length of input and the output will have hyphens on same locations as input

for example, if input `9-9999-9999` is passed then random output could be `1-2234-5678` (match hyphen location)
for example, if input `99999999-9` is passed then random output could be `12234567-8` (match hyphen location)

```
public String GenerateNumber(String input)
{
    //find the location of hyphens in the input
    String output = Generate random number of same length as input //ToString();
   //put hyphens on the random number generated above at the same locations matching input
   return output
}
```

Would be helpful if sample code provided in C# but java would also work.

Comment: Example inputs "999-99-9999", "99-999-9999",  "9-9999-9999", "999999999", "99999999-9

Comment: "Would be helpful if sample code provided in C#" We are not a code writing service. What have you tried and how does it not work?

Comment: It's also unclear what your actual question is. You have written a very vague description of what the program should do, but other than "can you write the code for me?" there is no true question.

Comment: You can use the [String.IndexOf Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find the locations of the hyphens in the original string. Although for such a short string, a `for` loop checking each character would do just as well.

Comment: I think you're trying to generate a number which is the same pattern as the input number, only with different numeric values.  The solution is to count how many numeric digits appear in the string, then generate that many random digits.  After this, replace each digit in the string with the new digit - thus preserving the format.

Comment: Dear "gunr2171" if you are admin then you can simply delete the question. But saying something "We are not a code writing service." was not needed. The problem seems very simple on the surface (theoretically) but it is not. I have got lot of theoretical answers here at my workplace but when tried in code , it doe not work. That is why I requested some code guidance. Thank you

Comment: @AmarjitDhillon, I'm not an admin. If you wish to discuss this question you may do so on [meta].

Comment: public static String GenerateNumber(String input)
        {
            //find the location of hyphens in the input
            Random ran = new Random();
            String output = input.ToCharArray()
                .Aggregate("", (xs, x) => xs + (x == '-' ? "-" : ran.Next(10).ToString()));
            //put hyphens on the random number generated above at the same locations matching input
            return output;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it.

```
public string GenerateNumber(string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
    }

    Random rand = new Random();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == '-')
        {
            builder.Append("-");
        }
        else
        {
            builder.Append(rand.Next(0, 9).ToString());
        }
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```